# Need figure to break/ignore page margin

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx, margins

I'm writing a report in LyX (using a personalized classicthesis-LyX) and I have troubles with my figures.

What I want is to **force a figure to break the page margin** in order to center it (without losing readability as consequence of resizing) (see attached picture for pdf output).

[image: goal]

Rotating the graphic/page is not an option. Here is a picture of how it is written in LyX.

[image: lyx]

Comment: have a look at the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package. You can then use, for example,  `\begin{figure}\begin{adjustwidth}{3cm}{}<figure code>\end{adjustwidth}\end{figure}`

Comment: I've used `centerline` (just put ERT `\centerline{` and another ERT after `}` for such issues in the past, but I've learned that it is not recommended: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113257/how-can-i-fix-this-overfull-hbox/113260#113260

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the best is simply fix the width of the image to `\linewidth,` but in other case, another way that seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htp]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\caption{The caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In Lyx simply change your image by an ERT box with the line of `\makebox` (of course, with the right image name) or if you want  left the image to lyx, add an ERT box with
`\makebox[\textwidth][c]{` just before the image and `}` just after the image. The source code will be the same.

[image: MWE]