# Centering a very wide deluxetable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align, aastex, deluxetable

I am using [aastex61.cls](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aastex61.cls). I have a deluxetable that is wide and runs off the side of the page. If the table were centered however, it would fit within the page sides. How can I center the table?

Minimal working example (also [here on ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59c8f81f74079a07f7f33f32)):

```
\documentclass[modern]{aastex61}

\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}

\received{...}
\revised{...}
\accepted{...}
\submitjournal{ApJ}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files 
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage{bm}         % Bold maths symbols, including upright Greek 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   % for mathscr characters 
\usepackage{natbib}     % Bibliography
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\shorttitle{Deluxe Table Test}
\shortauthors{asdf}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand{\myemail}{fdsa}

\begin{document}

\title{Deluxe Table Test} 
\correspondingauthor{Me}
\email{fdsa}
\author{asdf}

\startlongtable
\begin{deluxetable*}{llcccccccc}
\tablecaption{fdsafdsa. 
\label{tab:stellar-parameters}}
\tablecolumns{8}
\tablenum{1}
\tablewidth{0pt}
%\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead{
    \colhead{asdf} &
    \colhead{fdsa} &
    \colhead{sadf} &
    \colhead{dsa} &
    \colhead{fdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsaf} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} \\
    \colhead{} &
    \colhead{} &
    \colhead{asdf} &
    \colhead{dsa} &
    \colhead{fsda} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsafdsafd} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsafd} \\
    \colhead{} &
    \colhead{} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsafdsa} &
    \colhead{fdsafds} &
    \colhead{fdsafds} &
    \colhead{}
}
\startdata 
    432432 & 32432432 & 43243243 & 432 $\pm$ 4432 & 432432 $\pm$ 432432 & 543232 $\pm$ 54325 & 54332 $\pm$ 23133 & 5432543 \\
\enddata 
\end{deluxetable*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153730/143325?

Comment: @magula Yes, it doesn't seem to work. I have put the \makebox at various places around the table but it just seems to break the TeX.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron hi. i work for the folks who maintain AASTeX. This looks like a bug in `startlongtable` as removing it allows the text to overflow both margins. I reported this apparent bug here: https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/56

Comment: I ran into the same issue today, even using the aastex631 class file. In addition, \begin{table*} and \begin{rotatetable*} environment also does not center the table.

Answer (score 1):

Im aware this is a very old post but I ran into the same issue today and found a workaround for those who are willing to sacrifice the size of their table.
I was able to shrink my too-wide table using `\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}` and now it fits nicely within the page margins and is centered.